Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'openssl/asn1t.h' file not found Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'openssl/evp.h' file not found
I am getting this error while building my flutter app in iPhone 16 pro,
please tell me how to fix this issue.
I have tried adding openssl paths to the header search paths in xcode and library search path, but it didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
